# backbone.validation plugin and server side validations

Tags: validation, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm using the [Backbone.Validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) plugin. I have a model that does a uniqueness check that is done server-side. How would I get backbone.validation to recognize the errors and run the callbacks I have set up to display the error messages returned?

```
this.model.save()
  .done(function(model) {
    App.currentRouter.navigate('#/', {trigger: true});
   })
   .fail(function(response) {
     alert('errors: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
     // ? have backbone.validation handle errors ?
   });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

So not sure if this is the best way to do this but I found a solution that works.

```
  this.model.save()
    .done(function(model, response, options) {
      App.protocols.add(model);
      App.currentRouter.navigate('#/', {trigger: true});
    })
    .fail(function(response, xhr, options) {
      var errors = JSON.parse(response.responseText)['errors'];

      _.each(errors, function(val, attr){
        Backbone.Validation.callbacks.invalid(self, attr, val, 'name');
      });

      self.model.trigger('validated', false, self.model, errors);
      self.model.trigger('validated:invalid', self.model, errors);
    });
```